# Page Icon does not appear, only the page title - android

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I am using `PageIndicator` with `ViewPager` , but only the page title appears. The page icons don't appear. Does any one know why? Here is my adapter.

```
class GoogleMusicAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter {
    public GoogleMusicAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
    }

    @Override public int getIconResId(int index) {
      return ICONS[index];
    }

  @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return CONTENT.length;
    }
}
```

My Adapter

```
public class FavouritePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements
        IconPagerAdapter, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
private static final int FAVOURITE_EPISODE_INDEX = 0;
private static final int FAVOURITE_SHOW_INDEX = 1;
private static final int NUMBER_OF_PAGES = 2;

private static final String[] FAVOURITE_TITLES = {
        Util.getApplicationContext().getString(
                R.string.favourite_title_episode),
        Util.getApplicationContext().getString(
                R.string.favourite_title_show) };

public static final String TAG_EMPTY_EPISODE = "emtpy_episode";
public static final String TAG_EMPTY_SHOW = "empty_show";
public static final String TAG_LOADING_EPISODE = "loading_epsiode";
public static final String TAG_LOADING_SHOW = "loading_show";

WeakReference<Activity> acitivity;
WeakReference<FavouriteFragment> favouriteFragment;
FavouriteEpisodeAdapter mFavouriteEpisodeAdapter;
FavouriteShowAdapter mFavouriteShowAdapter;

public FavouritePagerAdapter(FavouriteFragment fr, Activity a,
        ArrayList<EpisodeInfo> episode, ArrayList<ShowData> show) {
    super();
    this.favouriteFragment = new WeakReference<FavouriteFragment>(fr);
    this.acitivity = new WeakReference<Activity>(a);
    mFavouriteEpisodeAdapter = new FavouriteEpisodeAdapter(a,
            R.id.textView1, episode);
    mFavouriteShowAdapter = new FavouriteShowAdapter(a, R.id.textView1,
            show);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    Log.d("getPageTitle", FAVOURITE_TITLES[position]);
    return FAVOURITE_TITLES[position];

}

@Override
public int getIconResId(int index) {
    return R.drawable.ic_action_search;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUMBER_OF_PAGES;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
    View v = this.acitivity.get().getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.favourite_episode_fragment_layout, null);
    ListView list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    TextView empty_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.empty);
    View loadingView = v.findViewById(R.id.loadingView);
    switch (position) {
    case FAVOURITE_EPISODE_INDEX:
        list.setAdapter(getmFavouriteEpisodeAdapter());
        empty_text.setText(Util.getApplicationContext().getString(
                R.string.favourite_empty_episode));
        empty_text.setTag(TAG_EMPTY_EPISODE);
        loadingView.setTag(TAG_LOADING_EPISODE);
        if (favouriteFragment.get().episodeInitialized.get()
                && getmFavouriteEpisodeAdapter().getCount() == 0) {
            loadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            empty_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        break;
    case FAVOURITE_SHOW_INDEX:
        list.setAdapter(getmFavouriteShowAdapter());
        empty_text.setText(Util.getApplicationContext().getString(
                R.string.favourite_empty_show));
        empty_text.setTag(TAG_EMPTY_SHOW);
        loadingView.setTag(TAG_LOADING_SHOW);
        if (favouriteFragment.get().showInitialized.get()
                && getmFavouriteShowAdapter().getCount() == 0) {
            empty_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        break;
    }
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(v, 0);
    if (((ViewPager) container).getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        favouriteFragment.get().loadEpisode();
    }

    return v;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == arg1;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
}

public FavouriteEpisodeAdapter getmFavouriteEpisodeAdapter() {
    return mFavouriteEpisodeAdapter;
}

public void setmFavouriteEpisodeAdapter(
        FavouriteEpisodeAdapter mFavouriteEpisodeAdapter) {
    this.mFavouriteEpisodeAdapter = mFavouriteEpisodeAdapter;
}

public FavouriteShowAdapter getmFavouriteShowAdapter() {
    return mFavouriteShowAdapter;
}

public void setmFavouriteShowAdapter(
        FavouriteShowAdapter mFavouriteShowAdapter) {
    this.mFavouriteShowAdapter = mFavouriteShowAdapter;
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    figureWhichToLoad(arg0);
}

private void figureWhichToLoad(int arg0) {
    try {
        switch (arg0) {
        case 0:// episode
            favouriteFragment.get().loadEpisode();
            break;
        case 1:// show
            favouriteFragment.get().loadShow();
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you running the sample project or are you copying into your own project?

Comment: i doesnot work in my project ... i have implement the IconPagerAdapter but it overriding function doesnot get called at run time

Comment: Please post your full activity code.