# FragmentAdapter only gives back page titles (Strings) instead of page icons

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have an activity with a tablayout menu with icons and a viewpager in it. If I use the Fragment Activity then my Icons disappear and I only get Strings back instead of the icons.

Unfortunately the `public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)` method can't be modified to something like `public int getPageTitle(int position)`.

Does a FragmentAdapter exist which gives back icons instead of strings or how can I modify the "getPageTitle" method to get back Icons?

I found a similiar question to my problem, but its still unanswered:
[Page Icon does not appear, only the page title - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578739/page-icon-does-not-appear-only-the-page-title-android)

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260384/how-to-add-page-title-and-icon-in-android-fragmentpageradapter

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way to use a FragmentPager with a TabLayout without missing Icons:

[Design support library tabs with only icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165306/design-support-library-tabs-with-only-icons/32173670#32173670)